# Can a Kohen refuse Pidyon Haben money

Tags: halacha, kohen-priest, money, yoreh-deah, pidyon-haben

According to Halacha, first born (naturally born) Jewish non-kohen/non-levite boys need to be redeemed to a Kohen through Pidyon Haben. My question is, can a Kohen refuse the 5 Shekels at the Pidyon Haben ceremony? Or is there an obligation on him to take it just as there is on the father to give it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Kohen has the ability to  refuse to accept the money of the Pidyon Haben. However, the Pidyon Haben may take effect regardless.

Ketzos HaChoshen (243:4) quotes Pri Chadash (Kuntras Mayim Chaim) that "נתינה בעל כרחה שמיה נתינה", including by *matnos kehuna*. In a town where there was only one Kohen who refused to redeem a specific baby, the Pri Chadash ruled that the *pidyon* takes effect without the Kohen's consent.

> והא דבעי לה בפ' מי שאחזו נתינה בע"כ שמיה נתינה כבר כתב הרשב"א בחידושיו
> שם דע"כ לא מיבעיא ליה אלא בנתינה בע"כ גבי תנאי דהוי חיובו של נותן אבל
> בחוב כיון דהוא חיובו של הלוה נפטר בחיובו בע"כ של המלוה ואין אנו יכולין
> להעמידו בחובו בע"כ אם רוצה ליפטר מחיובו ע"ש. **וא"כ במתנות כהונה נמי
> אפילו בע"כ שמיה נתינה וכמ"ש בקונטרוס מים חיים שם בשו"ת שהיה כהן א'
> בכפר וישראל אחד היה צריך לפדות בן בכור והכהן לא רצה לקבל והעלה שם
> בתשו' דנתינה בע"כ שמיה לתינה** ע"ש

However, Ketzos Hachoshen cites Tosfos (Kiddushin 8a) who seems to hold that a certain level of *daas* from the Kohen is necessary. Chazon Ish (EH 148) edits Tosfos to avoid this inference.

Comment: This is saying he acquires it even without his consent, not that the redemption is effective without him acquiring the money

Comment: How do you know your first sentence is true? Maybe it's a bittul aseh or something? מבזה קדשים?

Comment: @DoubleAA - No, he doesn't acquire it, but the redemption takes place nonetheless. See the continuation of Ketzos (specifically דלא אמרו בע"כ שמיה נתינה אלא שיפטור הנותן מחיובו אבל המקבל אם אינו רוצה אינו זוכה בע"כ כמ"ש שם הרשב"א בפ' מי שאחזו ע"ש וה"נ אם הנותן נותן מתנות בע"כ שמיה נתינה שלא להעמידו בחיובו בע"כ אבל הכהן נמי אינו זוכה בע"כ)

Comment: @DoubleAA - Edited to reflect your second comment. I wasn't discussing the permissibility of refusing.  Will hopefully update later to discuss that permissibility.